# MongoDB greater than numberLong issue

Tags: string, mongodb, date, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to get all documents in a collection in which the date, stored as this:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5c500ff8df157e051961cfab"
  },
  "date": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1548750839931"
    }
  },
  "when": "2019-1-29T8:33Z",
  "score": 20
}
```

... is greater than this: 1546300800000

I have 2 records in my collection, but I get none in return?

Here is my query:

```
{"date":{"$gt": 1546300800000}}
```

I guess that is has something to do with the date is stored as string, but can it be done?

Hoping for help and many thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your date is saved as `Date` type and you are using timestamp to find the documents.

So, You can first convert `date` to timestamp using [**`$toLong`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLong/) aggregation operator and then use [**`$gt`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/) operator

If you are using mongodb **4.0**

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$gt": [{ "$toLong": "$date" }, 1546300800000]
  }
})
```

If you are using mongodb **3.6**

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$gt": [
      { "$subtract": ["$date", new Date("1970-01-01")] },
      1546300800000
    ]
  }
})
```

or you can simply convert your `timestamp` to type `date`

```
db.collection.find({
  "date": { "$gt": new Date(1546300800000) }
})
```

Comment: cant seem to make these work... Would it be possible to just convert, in the find() query, to an int?